# Binding a logout method in angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-ngfor

I am trying to bind a logout function to a menu item that is being populated dynamically, When someone clicked logout it signs out the user. I have tried the follow code but seems not to be working.

Here is my `component.ts` file

```
usermenu: Object[] = [ {
    icon: 'tune',
    route: '/dashboard/settings',
    title: 'Account settings'
  }, {
    icon: 'exit_to_app',
    route: '',
    title: 'Sign out',
    method: 'logout()'
  },
];

logout(){
  //my code
}
```

My `template.html`

```
  <md-nav-list>
    <a *ngFor="let item of usermenu" [routerLink]="item.route" md-list-item (click)="item.method" ><md-icon>{{item.icon}}</md-icon>{{item.title}}</a>
  </md-nav-list>
```

For example when I click on account setting it redirects to setting comment, which is simple in this case. For signing out it won't be a component but a method which I have created `logout()`. Am looking on way I can bind it to the route when clicked it will log the user out.

Comment: Just trying to make sure I understand: You want to bind the logout method to your `<a>` tag, right?

Comment: Yes, but dynamically as you can see am using ngFor to pic data from the component if manually put the using (click)="logout()" it will affect setting one.

Comment: You can put the logout() method manually. I don't see any reason why you can't

Comment: I added a new item in user menu[] method and on my templated used (click)="item.method", but still was not working.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am absolutely not understanding what you're trying to do

Comment: Oh! I think I've got it

Comment: change your method to `method: 'logout'`. Then in your template, do `(click)="item.method()"`. See if that works

Comment: Produces same results the one I did above.

Comment: That's right, sorry. I meant this:
`(click)="eval(x.method)()"`. If it doesn't work from the template, you can wrap `eval` in your own method called `myEval` like so: `myEval(arg) {eval(arg)()}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UWLgn5B6ADLc26mgHWDb?p=info

I modified:

```
usermenu: Object[] = [ {
    icon: 'tune',
    route: '/dashboard/settings',
    title: 'Account settings',
method: ()=>{}
  }, {
    icon: 'exit_to_app',
    route: '',
    title: 'Sign out',
    method: this.logout
  },
];
```

And in the template:

```
<a *ngFor="let item of usermenu" [routerLink]="item.route" md-list-item (click)="item.method()" >
          <md-icon>{{item.icon}}</md-icon>
          {{item.title}}
        </a>
```

So basically you have to add a default arrow function for every link that dont have an operation, I think that inst really smart, but it works.